# How to apply a formatter to a unique form in Play 2?

Tags: forms, date, playframework-2.3, formatter

My application is using Play 2.3.7.

I have a form that needs a special formatter for a date. So I do this in the method of my controller that creates the form and renders the view :

```
Formatters.register(Date.class, new SimpleFormatter<Date>() {
    private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    @Override
    public Date parse(String input, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        try {
            return formatter.parse(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // We catch the error because it should be transparent for the user
            Logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String print(Date input, Locale locale) {
        return formatter.format(input);
    }
});
```

The problem is that this formatter is applied globally to all my application. And my other forms are using another date format : dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss (french format).
So how can I apply a formatter to only one form or at least, unregister a formatter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of `Formats` annotations and annotate a form field as follows:

```
public class SampleForm {

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date date;

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the job for my problem. However, the question is still applicable for someone who wants to apply a formatter only for one form and not the forms of the entire application.